# How to open a menu tied to ttk.Menubutton when hovering over it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menu, ttk

I wanted to make a custom menu bar in `Tkinter`, but since it was impossible to adjust, I had to make crutches. I made a custom menu from `Frame`,`Button` and `Menubutton`. But I met with a small problem - I can’t open the Menu when hovering over `ttk.Menubutton`. That is, I need that when hovering over Menubutton the Menu attached to this button opens (simulating clicking on `Menubutton`). How can this be implemented?

### Code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.option_add("*Menu.borderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.activeBorderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.background", "black")


style = ttk.Style(root)

fr = ttk.Frame(root)

btn_menu = ttk.Menubutton(fr, text='fegvd')
btn_menu.grid(row=0, column=0)

btn =ttk.Button(fr, text='grfbvgfev')
btn.grid(row=0, column=1)

btn_menu_st = ttk.Menubutton(fr, text='Gds')
btn_menu_st.grid(row=0, column=2)

fr.pack(fill='x')


file = tk.Menu(btn_menu, tearoff=0, foreground='white')
file.add_command(label='ГЫГ')

style = tk.Menu(btn_menu_st, tearoff=0, foreground='white')
style.add_command(label='Ugu')

btn_menu.configure(menu=file)
btn_menu_st.configure(menu=style)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is better idea to achieve it.My idea is to send a mouse event.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.option_add("*Menu.borderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.activeBorderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.background", "black")


style = ttk.Style(root)

fr = ttk.Frame(root)

btn_menu = ttk.Menubutton(fr, text='fegvd')
btn_menu.grid(row=0, column=0)

def func1(e):
    e.widget.event_generate("<Button-1>") # send a mouse press event

btn_menu.bind("<Enter>",func1) # when your mouse enter this widget
btn =ttk.Button(fr, text='grfbvgfev')
btn.grid(row=0, column=1)

btn_menu_st = ttk.Menubutton(fr, text='Gds')
btn_menu_st.grid(row=0, column=2)

fr.pack(fill='x')


file = tk.Menu(btn_menu, tearoff=0, foreground='white')
file.add_command(label='ГЫГ')

style = tk.Menu(btn_menu_st, tearoff=0, foreground='white')
style.add_command(label='Ugu')

btn_menu.configure(menu=file)
btn_menu_st.configure(menu=style)


root.mainloop()
```

---

I found `.post` can be a good way to do.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.option_add("*Menu.borderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.activeBorderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.background", "black")


style = ttk.Style(root)

fr = ttk.Frame(root)

btn_menu = ttk.Menubutton(fr, text='fegvd')
btn_menu.grid(row=0, column=0)
def func1(e):
    file.post(e.widget.winfo_rootx(),e.widget.winfo_rooty()+e.widget.winfo_height())

btn_menu.bind("<Enter>",func1)
btn =ttk.Button(fr, text='grfbvgfev')
btn.grid(row=0, column=1)

btn_menu_st = ttk.Menubutton(fr, text='Gds')
btn_menu_st.grid(row=0, column=2)

fr.pack(fill='x')


file = tk.Menu(btn_menu, tearoff=0, foreground='white')
file.add_command(label='ГЫГ')

style = tk.Menu(btn_menu_st, tearoff=0, foreground='white')
style.add_command(label='Ugu')

btn_menu.configure(menu=file)
btn_menu_st.configure(menu=style)

root.mainloop()
```

But `.unpost` couldn't work in my PC,I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57159288/11811255)